# How to convert a photograph to look like a thermal infrared spectrum image?

Tags: infrared, infrared-conversion

Without using a thermal imaging camera, how can a photograph's white balance (tint, etc) or other settings be adjusted in order to achieve the look of the Predator vision from the movies. In layman's terms, how to segregate the contents of a photograph containing animate/inanimate objects which we outline and appoint to be constituted with red (hot), yellow and green color mappings according to the infrared color spectrum, against an inanimate landscape background that is primarily shades of blue (cold)? Some examples below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, downvoted because the question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to make duotones in Photoshop,  you can get something similar with a quadtone containing the four main colors and a Gaussian blur. But no program will know which is the hot or cold part of the photo, so the color adjustment must be manual.

[image: before/after]

[image: quadtone]

To differentiate the color zones you must manipulate the graphics of each ink so that the percentages are 100% in the chosen zones, the rest 0% or nothing.

As an example, the image below is the blue ink graph, which is 100% in the shadows (from 80 to 100):

[image: blue]

Edit the ink amount to soften the color joints:

[image]

Change inks positions and percentages to get the right effect:

[image: Last]

Comment: Nice! You beat me to it — you don't have access to infrared information, thus anything you do (as you so adeptly demonstrated!) will *not* be showing actual infrared information. By using an IR-modified camera, one might be able to better simulate this, but even so-called "deep IR" is not going to show you true thermal information.

Comment: is there an equivalent of Photoshop's quadtone effect in Darktable?